# jQuery: Get the attribute of a content

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of html like this:

```
<span class="date-display-start" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" 
content="2014-02-14T10:45:00-05:00">10am</span>
```

And I want to just use jQuery to grab the content attribute and put it in a variable then send that variable to the href tag. Here is my jQuery:

```
var stuff = ('.date-display-start').attr('content');
jQuery('#href-link').attr('href', stuff);
```

Here is the link i am trying to set the href for:

```
<a href="">link</a>
```

I feel like i am missing something silly. any ideas?

EDIT: Changed variable, forgot that i made that switch for SO.

Comment: If your variable is `stuff`, why are you using `calStartDate` on the next line? and the link you posted had no ID, let alone the one you specified.

Comment: Felix has a likely answer. Are you watching the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like you're missing `$` or `jQuery` to select element:

```
var stuff = $('.date-display-start').attr('content');
// -------  ^ or jQuery here
```

as well as changing `calStartDate` to `stuff` since you've assigned the value to `stuff` variable:

```
jQuery('#href-link').attr('href', stuff);
```

Comment: That did it! I knew it was something silly that i just couldn't figure out... Thank you though! I will mark your answer when SO allows me to.